# Why is $x\mapsto x$-th prime number a partial recursive function?

Tags: logic, computability

I think that partial recursive functions correspond to all computable functions. Thus, if we can write a computer program to represent a function, the function is partial recursive.

In computability theory, primitive recursive functions are a class of functions that are defined using primitive recursion and composition as central operations and are a strict subset of the total $\mu$-recursive functions.

From another view, we show that the function $p_i$ yielding the $i$-th prime number
is primitive recursive. and also we able to show that the predicate $\mathrm{Prime}(x)$ holding of prime numbers is primitive recursive.

My question is:

> Why is $f(x)=x$-th prime number a partial recursive function?

I have seen and understood the most definitions but I just could not understand how to show this function is partial recursive or not?

Comment: All primitive recursive functions are recursive. In the informal "if you can write a computer program for" writing such a program is trivial.

Comment: "partial recursive functions correspond to all computable functions." This sentence seems nonsensical. What "correspondence" do you mean precisely?

Comment: i think we have create one - to one map between them. i need evrey one help me in define clear description.

Comment: The function in this case is total.

Comment: @Davied: As André says, all primitive recursive functions are total recursive -- and all total recursive functions are in particular partial recursive. Here "partial" is the _less_ demanding condition. A "partial recursive" function is allowed to _but not required to_ be undefined for some inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As André Nicolsas commented, all primitive recursive functions are total recursive -- and all total recursive functions are in particular partial recursive.

Here "partial" is the *less* demanding condition. A "partial recursive" function is allowed to *but not required to* be undefined for some inputs.

Comment: @DaviedZuhraph: Well, you wrote in the question that you already know that the n-th prime function is partial recursive ...

Comment: @DaviedZuhraph: I don't understand what you're asking. You know (so you say) that the function is primitive recursive. All primitive functions are partial recursive. Therefore your function is partial recursive. -- There's your proof.